# Can a string-literal be returned without malloc/buffer

Tags: c

Is the following valid/acceptable C code to return a string-literal?

```
char* level_str(level)
{
    switch (level) {
        case DEBUG: return "DEBUG";
        case INFO:  return "INFO";
        case WARN:  return "WARN";
        case ERROR: return "ERROR";
        default:    return "UNKNOWN";
    }
}
```

Or, does the pointer to the string-literal become invalid/overridden on the stack once the function is returned? If so, are the only two valid ways to do this either (1) malloc the string; or (2) write to a callee-supplied buffer?

Comment: String literals are stored in `ready-only` section not on stack. So returning pointer to it from a function is safe.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica could you please clarify what you mean by that? Does that mean that the pointer/`char*` goes in the `rax` and the callee can use that and so the string-literals are fine?

Comment: The key is the address of a string literal (e.g. `"hello world"`) is fixed and good for the life of the program. So that address isn't destroyed when a function returns (it is just a read-only literal that is part of the executable). So unlike a locally declared array that is created on the function stack, a string literals address can be declared and returned from a function. At compile time, the compiler sees `"hello world"` and just makes it part of the `.rodata` section of the executable. With a `char array[12];` the compiler has no clue what it will be.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "read-only literal that is part of the executable ///" is an implementation detail - though common. Code nor the environment is required to have a "read-only" section.

Comment: OK, just about every other compiler on earth, except for the Non-Standard Conforming compilers written by Microsoft, string literals go in the read-only `.rodata` section of the executable... but, know that is an implementation detail, and there is a very popular compiler that lets you change string literals contrary to what most of the rest of the world does `:)` [C11 Standard - 6.4.5(p7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7) `"If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a string-literal be returned without malloc/buffer

Yes.  The address of the string literal can be retuned.

OP's code is fine, but better as `const char* level_str(level)` as the data `const char *` points to and *string literals* are best left alone without attempting to change.

To attempt to change a string literal is *undefined behavior* (UB).  Might work might not, might crash, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a string literal behaves as a pointer to an array of `char` having **static storage duration** and initialized with the given characters plus a terminating null.  This means it is similar to if you had written `static char my_debug_string[] = { 'D', 'E', 'B', 'U', 'G', 0 };` and returned a pointer to `my_debug_string` (except that you must not modify the array).   In particular the lifetime of this array is the entire lifetime of the program; it remains valid after the return from the function where it appeared.

Reference: C17 standard 6.4.5 (6-7).